# What would be a good way to get GPU information (especially the name) in C?

Tags: c, linux, gpu

I would need a mostly universal way to get the product name of the currently installed GPU (possibly as a `char*`) that works on at least most linux-based OSs.

I would really avoid using a `fork()` with an `exec()` and parse the output of `lspci`, since it would likely be a pain to support most currently running GPUs that way

I wish somebody here is able to provide a good way to get this info, thanks a lot in advance :)

Comment: The OpenGL and Vulkan API’s both have ways to obtain this information. They are not, however, a C standard library

Comment: Does `glxinfo` contain the string you are looking for?  (The code `glxinfo` uses to retrieve  those strings is much simpler and easier to do from your code than reinventing `lspci` inside your program)  How about `xdpyinfo` ?